# Redux-Persist Changes State after Application is ReHydrated

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-persist

Working on something similar to Jotform.

This is my state:

```js
const InitialState = {
  BaseContainerEl: []
}
```

This is my approach, let's say I want to create Full Name fields (i.e three inputs with first, middle and last names). So, I create a component that renders a p-tag and onClick it runs the updateBase function where I stored the exact result (i.e the 3 inputs) in a variable 'el' and it update's the state using the virtual DOM created and stored in 'el'.
**And it works fine, because after updating the state I render the element.**

```js
const FullName = (props: any) => {

  const updateBase = () => {
    const key = uuidv4();
    const el = (
      <BaseContainer key={key} id={key}>
        <InputCustom
          placeholder='First Name'
          type='text'
          label='First Name'
          formControl='form-control form-control-sm'
          style={{ width: '90%' }}
        />
        <InputCustom
          placeholder='Middle Name'
          type='text'
          label='Middle Name'
          formControl='form-control form-control-sm'
          style={{ width: '90%' }}
        />
        <InputCustom
          placeholder='Last Name'
          type='text'
          label='Last Name'
          formControl='form-control form-control-sm'
          style={{ width: '90%' }}
        />
      </BaseContainer>
    );

    props.updateBaseContainerEl(el)
  }
  return (
    <p draggable onClick={updateBase} className="text-muted" style={{
      borderRadius: '2px',
      boxShadow: ' 20px 20px 60px #bebebe-20px -20px 60px #ffffff',
    }}>
      <i className="fe fe-user" style={{
      }}></i>
      Full Name
    </p>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

This the problem:
I am persisting the state using redux-persit, now when I refresh the application it rehydrates and after rehydration the virtual DOM stored in the state (i.e the react component) changes with some properties and values missing. According to the redux-persist docs, there are some values in javascript that cannot be represented in json.

So, it errors out: `Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, key, ref, props, _owner, _store}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Below are images of what it looks like before rehydration and after.
[image: Before Hydration]

[image: After hydration]

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Why are you trying to store the element into state? probably you want to be storing the actual data right? not the functions

Comment: Well, I am storing the element into the state because I considered the flow to be scalable and readable especially to new devs coming on board, and I will need the data and the functions because they are custom components and they have an impact on the view.

Comment: Anyways I think you answered your own question, you can't store function (components / elements) into localstorage because they're not serializable. you'll need to store data then recreate your view from your data

Comment: Alright @azium, thank you.